# where is fsync() defined in kernel?

Tags: function, linux-kernel

In kernel 2.4.37, there is a file operation, `file->f_op->fsync(struct file *, struct dentry *, int)`, I'm trying to track this `fsync` down to know how it works, but I can't find where it's defined. Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Different filesystems implements `fsync` file operation differently. You can `grep` kernel sources under fs/ directory for `.fsync` substring. Usually this substring occures in `.fsync = <func_name>` expression, where <func_name> is actual implementation of the operation. If you want to find `fsync` **syscall** implementation, look for function named `sys_fsync` instead.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for your reply. I have tried that and it works for me :)